# Reduce image quality on the fly and display lower quality version

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a competition website that uses Wordpress allowing users to submit images. There are 700+ entries with up to 6 images each, with a maximum filesize of 3mb for each image.

I've then listed all the entries as posts, then on each post it displays the images.

Each image is displayed using `the_field('image1');`, `the_field('image2');`, `the_field('image3');` etc.

The problem I have is that the page is then trying to load 6 images at 3mb's a time. Is there a way to optimise the image on the fly and show it at 50% quality?

Comment: A usual web image cannot exceed a 150k. Where did you get 3Mb?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not really sure how to answer that - the image the person uploaded is 3mb, the file in the uploads section of Wordpress is 3mb and when it's displayed on the page and downloaded it's 3mb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resize the picture on the fly after extracting it from a database (or file) without having to create another temporary file. Presumably you have a URL which gets an image from the database.

```
$pdo = new PDO("somewhere");
$sql = "SELECT image_data FROM pictures WHERE id=1";

$stmt = $pdo->query( $sql );
$obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$img = imagecreatefromstring($obj->image_data);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img, NULL, 50);

imagedestroy($img);
```

If you pass NULL as a file name to `imagejpeg` it will write the jpeg to standard out. The 3rd parameter is the quality level, in this case 50%.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file =  $_GET['file'];//URL with img parameter http://localhost/fk/test.php?file=1.jpeg
$quality = 40; //Change What quality you needed
$location = "images/".$file;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagejpeg($image, $location, $quality) ;
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($location));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file.'"');
    echo file_get_contents($location);
```

Comment: Post already answered, next time please give additional information as links and check other comments to see if post needs an update. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When the image is uploaded , you could save 2 images. 
1. The original image
2. A low resolution copy of the image

So when the user views the page, the low res image is shown initially while the original image is being downloaded in the background.

You could easily find some ready code to resize images through php. Like this one.
http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: The images have already been uploaded so I can't do it on upload. I thought there was some native Wordpress function to do this but it doesn't seem the case. Is there a way to do it without re-saving the image? I know that may be server heavy but we have a huge server to handle this and anything is an improvement on 18mb of images trying to load at once!

Comment: You could apply a batch code which would generate low resolution copies of all images already on the server.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to resize images on the fly. There is only straight way to make CPU choke with such a denial-of-service self-attack.

Images have to be pre-resized to reasonable size and quality right after upload. Every web-site in the world does it this way.

Comment: When I load the page it literally chugs along and you can see the image slowly loading - it's definitely 3mb.